# Is there an easy way to route IP packets from a user space Windows app to the network?

Tags: windows, routes, tcp, ethernet, ipv4

I am working on a project that involves a usb device, through which we will receive ip packets from a remote pc. We assign the remote pc its IP Address. I have been experimenting with sending raw ip packets via several methods:

1 - raw sockets: ping works fine, problems sending tcp

2 - tun/tap W32: I managed to get this working enough to send pings out and get pings back to the phy ethernet device, but could not read them using ReadFile(...) on the driver guid.

3 - winpcap: ping works, out going tcp shows up on wireshark(so I assume it is leaving the pc), but i never get an ack to my syn. Im also worried that if I did get an ack the windows TCP stack would send a rst.

Our goal is to be a transparent pass through from the client pc to the network.
Client <-wrapped ip packet-> [device] <-wrapped ip packet-> WinPC <- IP -> IpNetwork

Its possible that im going about this wrong, seems like this should be easier.

I realize that windows is prob not the ideal OS for this, however I have no control over the OS.

thanks in advance

Comment: Your issue with tun/tap sounds like a routing issue - perhaps IP forwarding is disabled in the registry?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed my issue with TCP Syn packets not getting acked, turns out I forgot to include the pseudo-header when calculating the TCP header checksum. Now it looks like the tcp handshake completes, so im calling this problem solved. If anyone feels like recomending a better way to accomplish this, feel free to reply. For now looks like we will use the winpcap method.

Update:
For this to work without windows constantly RST'ing tcp connections, you have to enable internet connection sharing(ICS) on the adapter you are sending packets out of. Other than that this ended up working for us.